# TP-Link Powerline connection issue

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I'm using a Powerline adaptor to connect a camera to the local network however I cannot get the powerline LED to light up between the two devices (both have been paired). The Internet/Ethernet light is however flashing suggesting that a connection is present between the two devices.

The end result is the camera is not detected on the network (Not showing up in the DHCP pool). Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tested them in the same room - i.e. made absolutely sure they work when on the same ring main?

Comment: even in adjacent power sockets. Anyhow, include a picture.. And call TP Link, they know what their LEDs mean. And forget a camera, just try to connect a computer.

Comment: I recall once hearing that the TP link powerline things had an issue where they only synced when a cable was connected to them.. though that isn't your issue at the moment but is worth knowing about. Also sometimes an ISP if they provided them, can offer technical support too. And TP Link if they think they're faulty based on their doagnosis with you over the phone, may offer a replacement IIRC. Or they may solve it

Comment: connecting on the same ring they work, they have been working near to the current installed point on a different socket but for reasons too complex to go into I've got another socket installed by an electrician (solid core cable not twisted pair like in extension cables) which it no longer works in. My main question really was the "Powerline" light is not lit up but the ethernet one is suggesting data transfer. I'll give TP a try.